# I cannot install any version of Visual Studio in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2010

I've tried 2008, 2010 and 2012...I need Visual Studio installed so I can compile Python and NodeJS packages. Every version I've tried just flashes the Visual Studio splash screen and then does nothing.

I've tried from the EXE and the ISO and they do the same thing.

Any idea what could possibly be preventing me from installing, in this case, just visual studio?

Comment: do you have a log file in TEMP folder? Does it include anything useful?

Comment: Nothing stands out... are you talking about C:\Temp?

Comment: look here: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: `Error 0x80131902: Failed to create the managed bootstrapper application.`
Error 0x80131902: Failed to create UX.
`Error 0x80131902: Failed to load UX.`
Error 0x80131902: Failed while running
...
`Error 0x80131902: Failed to run per-user mode.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working after about 6 months. This is what I did.

1. I went into Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Windows Features

   1. **disabled .NET 3.5**
   2. **enabled everything in .NET 4.0**
2. I went online and downloaded **Microsoft .NET 4.5.2 and DirectX** and installed them.
3. Then I restarted my computer...at this point it said I had updates that I didn't have before.
4. Installed Visual Studio (as **administrator**) Successfully
5. Restart Computer
6. Re-enabled .NET 3.5 and disable relevent .NET 4.0 features

Suggestions for solving this problem came from [here](http://ricardodsanchez.com/2014/04/11/error-0x80131902-failed-to-create-the-managed-bootstrapper-application/) .. though most didn't work for me, the above combination did.

Thanks @magicandre1981 for even telling me where the relevant `log` file was (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp)

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do was disable .NET Framework 3.5.1 in "Windows Features" on Windows 7, then the web installer of Visual Studio Community 2015 RC started working.

Comment: This helped me for windows 10. I just disabled .NET 3.5 and did a restart.

Comment: What worked for me on Windows 8.1 was just running .NET 4.5.2 installer and selecting `Repair`. I didn't even have to touch .NET 3.0 or restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the

`Failed to run per-user mode.`

problem also, so I followed speedy32's machine.config instruction from
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328758/visual-studio-2013-update-1-not-installing):

> In my case there was no C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config file. There was only machine.config.default. So I copy it and rename to machine.config

and it worked...